.setValue(null) vs .removeValue() in Firebase
What is the difference between .setValue(null) and .removeValue() to delete a value in the Firebase Realtime Database? I mean is there any technical reason to use a particular method?
I saw these two methods to delete a value in the Firebase Realtime Database and tried to search for the difference but couldn't find/understand an answer that helps.

There's no difference between setting a path to null or removing that path. The operations are equivalent, so you can use whatever feels most natural in your code.
